# Setting a Constant independent of executed Module

Tags: excel, vba

I try to Set a constant which should contain the Connection String for my Database. But the Setup for my macro is so that on the first Sheet in my Excel there are a lot of Buttons. Depending on which Button the user clicks another Module gets executed, but all of them connect to the same DB at some point.

Since I don't want to change the Connection String at many different points it should be done with one Constant.

But I can never tell which Module gets executed an which doesn't.

Therefore I created a new Module which only contains one Line of Code:

```
Public Const ConnectionString As String = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Database=X;User=root;Password=X;"
```

Unfortunately when a Button is clicked and some Module/Sub gets executed, the Variable "ConnectionString" Contains no Value.

How can I make sure that independent of the called Sub/Module the Constant is set?

Comment: change Public to Global. Works for me.

Comment: @MG92: And `Public` doesn't work? Practically both of them do the same. `Global` comes from older versions of VB and was likely kept for backwards compatibility. "`Global` can only be used in standard modules, whereas `Public` can be used in all contexts (modules, classes, controls, forms etc.)"

Comment: The single exception would be in a module having `Option Private Module`, which is very improbable to be your case. Do you mean that going in the module you want to test and putting there `Debug.Print ConnectionString` it does not return the constant value? If it returns it, the problem must be in a different place and you must bring your code using it and not returning its value...

Comment: @FaneDuru maybe the same name is redeclared in module/sub where it shows empty string.

Comment: @BrakNicku: Yes, it could be. Good point! But only in care if he uses `Dim ConnectionString As String` and do not allocate any value to the string. If he will use `ConnectionString = "xxx"` after declaration, VBA will return "xxx".

Comment: FaneDuru got it exactly right, I missed to delete the initialisation at the top of the module...
after deleting the "Dim ConnectionString as String" it works just fine, thanks alot guys. If you want post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @BrakNicku deserves all the credit! So, let him post the answer.

Comment: @FaneDuru I do not have time for that right now, so feel free to answer if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Public` constant must be used in all  contexts (modules, classes, controls, forms etc.), except two cases:

a. `Option Private Module` is in effect;

b. The constant has also been declared in modules/procedures (`Dim ConnectionString As String`) but **no value has been allocated**. If, after declaration, a value would be allocated (`ConnectionString = "xxx"`), then VBA will return "xxx". So looking for `ConnectionString As String` in all project, the place of the real problem will be descovered, I think.

But at least part of the credit must go to @BrakNicku, who firstly put in discussion the second possibility...